# Restricting discount code for 1 per registration

Tags: civievent, cividiscount, online-registration

I don't want to limit the total amount of discounts available, I only want to limit how many can be used per registration.

For example, we have an event that costs $75. Only 1 ticket can be discounted to $0. I have created a discount code for $75 that can only be applied to the ticket. However, if someone buys 2 tickets, instead of discounting $75 of the $150 originally owed, it's coming up as $0 owed.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Are you using a percentage or a set ($) amount with your discount code?